# Haproxy - allow access to just one address/file

Tags: acl, haproxy

I want to allow access to just one URL, something like:
https://something.com/Qweb/Common/UserSchedule.aspx

And I whish to block direct acces to any other files. Here's my config, but it's not working:

```
frontend                agendamento_frontend
```

```
    acl backend_acl_agendamento path_end -i UserSchedule.aspx
    acl backend_acl_agendamento path_beg -i /Qweb/common

    use_backend agendamento_backend if backend_acl_agendamento
```

```
What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.


Users can still accesss to other files like Login.aspx...
```